# how to fire my own activity when user clicks on the new sms notification

Tags: android, sms, notifications

hi guys i am looking for solution to fire my own activity to be lauched to handle incoming sms notification. i am not talking about receving broadcast of incoming sms but i want to launch my own activity when user clicks the new sms notification.Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notification is generated by the default sms application, so it is linked to it, you can't change that.
The only thing you can do is create by yourself a notification through a receiver/intent-filter and link it to the Activity you want to launch.

Comment: thats fine, So is there any way to disable the default sms app? what i mean to say is whenever a new sms comes the notification should not appear in drawer.

Comment: Notifications can be disabled from the setting screen of the default sms app. I don't think there is other ways do to that as you can't access its SharedPreferences, except maybe by uninstalling/disabling the app, but it would be more complicated than just uncheck a box.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate further on what @Lyrkan said, add the following to your manifest,

```
<receiver class=".SMSReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:value="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and make sure you have the appropriate permission, i.e.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
```

and the class you need to implement is something like

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override 
    public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent){
    //your code here
    }
}//end of class
```

Now from the onReceive you can do whatever it is that you want to do with the SMS.

Comment: i already know how to receive sms using this method. please read my question properly i am talking about sms notification that comes in drawer.

Comment: Apologies. My bad. Point taken.